# Rest API Get call is failing

Tags: flutter, rest

I am new in Flutter. while I am making `GET` call for the Rest API( https://execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Card/urn:CardAcctId:Headers.CardAcctId/Retrieve), getting `XMLHttpRequest error` as error message. Any thought will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the issue but no solution. , While calling rest api, the request header keys converted to lower case. We have some custom header and thats need to be case sensitive. Please let me know how to send the header as it is while calling the api as flutter is converting that to lower case? I am using flutter web.